# Installing VisualRuby on a MAC

Tags: ruby, macos, user-interface, gtk, glade

I'm trying to understand how to install visualruby on a MAC.  I work in ubuntu, and I've developed install instructions for Ubuntu and Windows, but I don't know the corresponding instructions for the MAC:

http://visualruby.net/Download

I know that you need to install the [Glade Interface Designer](http://glade.gnome.org/).  This should install the graphics toolkit, gtk2 as well.  Visualruby needs gtk2.  After that you can install visualruby:

gem install visualruby

My friend told me that it needs to be run in the X11 terminal.  I don't understand any of this.  I'd like to develop step-by-step instructions for installing it on the MAC that includes the correct version of Glade/Gtk2.  I know that visualruby requires Glade version 2.6 thru 2.8.  The latest version of Glade uses Gtk3 which isn't good.

EDIT:  Visualruby will also require "gtksourceview2" installed (perhaps via homebrew?)

Step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the friend referred to above.
I had the best success with QuartzX11. 
I installed glade, gtk+ and gtksourceview via homebrew but perhaps that's not the best way.